# Batch script ENDLOCAL / SET inside if statement is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I am new to batch scripts and I am writing a batch script to set the environment variable. Below is the batch script I use for it.

```
if 1 == 1 (
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    SET name1=%1_hello
    endlocal & SET name=%name1%
    echo varaiable %name%
    goto :eof
)
```

But I am facing the issue the variable `name` is not getting set and `name1` in `endlocal & SET name=%name1%` is always null or getting it from previously set environment variable.
But the same code without `if statement` works.

```
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    SET name1=%1_hello
    endlocal & SET name=%name1%
    echo varaiable %name%
    goto :eof
```

In the above code the `name1` variable is getting set and `name` is getting displayed. How can I get rid of this problem? Why `endlocal / set` behaves differently with if statement ?

Answer (score 4):

When the IF statement is parsed - and that's from the `IF` through to its closing parenthesis, ALL `%var%` are replaced by the contents of those variables as they stood at the time the line was PARSED, that is BEFORE execution.

Comment: So use conditional GOTO to jump over blocks of code, instead of conditional () blocks